# symfony2 multidelte records delete

Tags: symfony

i have a file called index which shows list of customer inquiry.
i want to put multiple delete in the that.

the code of my index file list is bellow.

```
 {% block body -%}
<h1>Enquiry list</h1>


<table class="records_list" id="rounded-corner">
    <thead>
        <tr>
    <th>Option</th>
    <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Body</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="multiSelect" id="multiSelect[]" value="{{ entity.id }}"></td>
            <td><a href="{{ path('enquiry_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.id }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.subject }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.body }}</td>
            <td>

                    <a href="{{ path('enquiry_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" title="View"><img src="http://test//bundles/blogger/image/view.png" style="width:30px; height:30px"></a>

                    <a href="{{ path('enquiry_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" title="Edit"> <img src="http://test//bundles/blogger/image/edit.png" style="width:30px; height:30px" > </a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    <tfooter>

    </tfooter>
</table>

    <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('enquiry_new') }}">
            Create a new entry
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

I have put the checkbox inside it.
and what i want is the array value of the "multiSelect[]" which store all id.
and i am passing this to my controller.
i donot know how to pass this array value as my controller argument. so please help me
i want to pass it here.

```
<tfooter>

      <a href="{{ path('enquiry_edit', " ")  }}">MultiDelete</a>

</tfooter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.
I have created the form and pass the request to the controller deleteAction .

in deleteAction method

i get the request parameters  using $request->get('multiSelect'); "multiSelect" the name of the input box.

and using the repositoryclass object i have completed the task.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) for that. Using input fields without a form is always a sloppy way.

Comment: i have use form field too it give me value in request context but i do not know how to parse it.

Comment: This is what forms are for. All values from a form will be send to the action-URL of a form. Either as POST or GET. You decided this through the action-attribute of the form tag. Plese read the documentation of forms in symfony2 that I linked above. It's pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most secure way to do this is with a link that onclick generates a form and send it by post. For example:

```
<a href="{{ path('your_delete_action', { 'id': object.id }) }}" 
   token="{{ token }}"
   data-method="POST"
   object-id ="{{ object.id }}">
   <span class="red"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
</a>
```

And onClick on this links you generate a form and send it to your deleteAction

```
// Every link with an attribute data-method
$("#container").on("click", "a[data-method]", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var target = $(event.currentTarget);
    var method = target.attr('data-method');
    var action = target.attr('href');
    var token = target.attr('token');
    var objectId = target.attr('object-id');

    // Create a form on click
    var formulario = $('<form/>', {
        style:  'display:none;',
        method: method,
        action: action
    });

    formulario.appendTo(target);

    formulario.append("<input name='token' value='" + token + "' type='hidden'/>");
    formulario.append("<input name='id' value='" + objectId + "' type='hidden'/>");

    // Do submit
    formulario.submit();

});
```